# Query to Split 1 column into two column count which one is zero the other is not

Tags: sql, group-by, count

I need help for this case.

I have this data as example :

[[data]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0l3fx.png)

My expected result will be :

```
Type     |  countzero    |  countnonzero

Savings  |     3         |    4

Current  |     2         |    3
```

Any help is really appreciate it... thanks guys.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `conditional aggregation`

```
select type, 
       count(case when soldo=0 then 1 end) as countzero,
       count(case when soldo>0 then 1 end) as countnonzero
from tablename
group by type
```